# Is it possible to get a Schengen visa without travel insurance and a copy of the itinerary?

Tags: visas, schengen, netherlands, south-africa

i'm an international student completing my study programm in South Africa. As vacations are coming soon, i would like to know travel for Europe, especially in Netherlands. I have so far all those documents:
- Valid Passport;
- Bank Statements of my uncle living in South Africa and a letter of support certifying that he will cover his nephew's trip; 
- Hotel reservation letter;
- The 2 photographs;
- The letter of the University that I do attend saying that I am allowed to go overseas and to be back for cayying on studying;
- Flight reservation;
- A copy of a past schengen visa issued in 2003 by the French consulate and an airline ticket of Airfrance (2003).

However, I do not have the travel/health/ insurance that covers 30.000 Euro; and a copy of the itinerary.

Is it possible under that condition to get a schengen visa? And also how to make an itinerary that can qualify me for the visa? And do I need extra documents?

Comment: You've asked multiple questions in one go. I'd recommend you to visit the [Travel.SE chat room](http://www.theatlanticcities.com/politics/2013/11/toronto-loves-its-cracked-mayor/7459/) for extended discussions about your case.

Comment: Yes, but everythng coming from you could be found valuable, so even though i was not specific or i asked to mich things at once, just give me please possible answers.

Comment: I'm sorry @user9040 but that's not how Stack Exchange works. They've provided us this site under the expectation that we operate it according to their policies. To understand how Stack Exchange works, [please have a look at their help pages](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help).